# Is there a layer that takes a tf vector of probabilities and returns a vector with the highest probability is set to 1 and 0 otherwise

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have

```py
layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
```

and this returns a probability for the three classes I have. I want to have it return just `[0,0,1]` if the softmax layer returns `[0.02,0.02,0.96]` for example. Would this improve my model?

Comment: These are two separate questions. Looking for a way to do it? There is an answer below. Would this improve your model? No, because such an operation is discontinuous and you cannot train the model with such an output layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Lambda layer:

```
l = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda x: tf.one_hot(tf.argmax(x, axis=1), depth=tf.shape(x)[-1])
)

l([[0.02, 0.02, 0.96]])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: `gather` and `eye` seems a bit complex IMHO -- you can also use `one_hot` directly on the argmax output.

Comment: Very true, I changed it slightly

Comment: I tried to put this lambda layer into a `keras.Sequential` model, but I ultimately got this error when I tried to train it: `No gradients provided for any variable:`. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I'm surprised you get this error. Can you provide minimal code reproducing this error, maybe with generated data?